# python "No module named setuptools" error

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to get [csvdedupe](https://github.com/datamade/csvdedupe#installation-and-dependencies) set up and I'm running into this error when I run the command

```
 `python setup.py install`
```

However, when I run

```
 pip install setuptools
```

I get the message

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I'm extremely new to this so any advice would be helpful!

Comment: Open setup.py and check the import

Comment: it says `from setuptools import setup`. Is that what it's supposed to say?

Comment: Yes mine says that as well

Comment: Do you include the backticks when running the command like you've posted?

Comment: Check that python and pip are in the same path. Setuptools may have been installed in a different Python environment than the one linked to your python executable. Use the which command, ie. which python; which pip

Comment: That's probably it, because my python and pip have different paths. Though ultimately I gave up and ended up just deduping the files with rails.

Answer (score 0):

Setuptools in written in one word : **setuptools** not **setup tools**
You should run :

```
pip install setuptools
```

Comment: Sorry, that was mistyped on the question. I had ran the command correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The message seems to be saying that someone had already installed setuptools on your system. It is telling you that you need to upgrade the already intalled version using the --upgrade argument. See the documentation for what is required.

If it is a matter of using setuptools then it is telling you that you do not need to install setuptool because it has already been done and to go to the next step.

Comment: When I run `pip install setuptools --upgrade` I get `Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and it still fails to install with the same `ImportError: No module named setuptools` error.

Comment: @greetification That means that it is already in your system. Go to the next step and use it. you should not need to install it.